# Select rows between, where column is of type varchar

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to do a mysql query to get all rows where a column is between two values.
The column is of type varchar.
For example:

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE column BETWEEN '6103' AND '6108'
```

The column is from type varchar and contains values like: '6103123', '6103123/17', '6104123', '6104124' ...

Comment: Why is your column a `varchar`, when you're actually storing numbers? What should happen with strings that are actually no numbers or which contain characters like `/`?

Comment: And what's wrong with your select statement? Doesn't it return the wanted rows already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE SUBSTRING(column,1,4) BETWEEN '6103' AND '6108'
```

Comment: Just another short question: When the 'from' and 'to' value are the same I get no results:
SELECT id FROM table WHERE SUBSTRING(column,1,4) BETWEEN '6103' AND '6103'

Comment: hahaha, don't use `BETWEEN`, just use `=`  or `IN`. Example : `WHERE SUBSTRING(column,1,4) = '6103'`  ; `WHERE SUBSTRING(column,1,4) IN '6103'`

Comment: Sorry, it also works with BETWEEN. I've just made a mistake... nevermind and thanks again

Comment: Anytime, don't forget thick as Answer ;)

Comment: But does MySQL really require SUBSTRING here?

Comment: @jarlh : do you have any better function than `SUBSTRING` ?

Comment: @ColourDalnet: No function at all, just column between... as the original query. What does MySQL return in that case?

Comment: @jarlh : Nice catch, I will check this first. What do you think Patricks?

Comment: I tried it without SUBSTRING. But that doesn't work for me. With SUBSTRING everyhting works fine

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE column BETWEEN '6103' AND '6108'
```

because '6103' <= '6103123' <= '6108'.